# Find transfer function of a simulink model

Tags: matlab, controls, simulink

I have a bit complicated simulink model of a power system. i want to find the transfer function of the system between two point of the model.
Is there a way to find tf or steady-state of the system?

Answer (score 1):

There a section in the doc on how to do this. Execute the following at the command line and select the link related to "Simulink > Simulation >".

```
>> docsearch('Trimming and Linearization')
```

Alternatively you can look directly at the documentation for the `linmod` function (or `linmod2`, or `dlinmod`, depending on what you need),

```
>> doc linmod
```

If you have access to it, there are also some interactive tools in the [Simulink Control Design](http://www.mathworks.com/products/simcontrol/) add-on product.

Note also that linearization of Simulink models is not typically a mindless process of pressing a button (or executing the `linmod` function) and get a good result.  You'll typically need to spend time determining appropriate steady-state conditions, and iteratively refining the linearization.

Comment: So, I didn't understand how can i find linear model and transfer function?

Comment: I've edited the above answer to include info on the exact function that you want to look at.  It's called `linmod`, and it is designed to return the state-space representation (or the numerator and demoninator) of the linear transfer function from model `Inports` to `Outports`.